# Прозрачные символы в с++ или взаимодействие через клавиатуру с элементами без ввода в консоль

Tags: c++, консоль

Практикуюсь в с++, хочу написать что то типа базы данных(в файле будет хранится числовая информация, до 8 символов из 0 и 1, либо сделаю вариант со скоростями, сравнивая их и тд.), пока на начальном уровне. Хочу при вводе записи для переменной firstChoose в консоли не отображалась переменная.(возможно криво сформулировал. Прошу помочь если вы можете)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
//#include <vector>

void MainMenu() {
    std::cout << "1.Add info" << std::endl
        << "2.Read info" << std::endl
        << "3.Exit";
}

void ReadInfo(std::string path, std::string msg) {
    std::fstream fs;
    try {
        fs.open(path, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
        std::cout << "Info from data base: " << std::endl;
        while (!fs.eof()) {
            if (fs.peek() == std::fstream::traits_type::eof()) {
                std::cout << "File empty" << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                msg = "";
                fs >> msg;
                std::cout << msg << " ";
            }
        }
        fs.close();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void EnterInfo(std::string path, std::string msg) {
    std::fstream fs;
    try {
        fs.open(path, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        std::cin >> msg;
        fs << "\\" << msg << "\\" << "\n";
        SetConsoleCP(866);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    std::cout << "Small data base for practice ^ - ^(Not real)" << std::endl;
    MainMenu();
    int firstChoose;
    std::cin >> firstChoose;
    std::string path = "data_base.txt";
    std::string msg;
    while (firstChoose != 1 && firstChoose != 2 && firstChoose != 3) {
        std::cin >> firstChoose;
        if (firstChoose == 1) {
            std::cout << "Enter info:" << std::endl;
            EnterInfo(path, msg);
        }
        else if (firstChoose == 2) {
            ReadInfo(path, msg);
        }
        else if (firstChoose == 3) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```